# How can I install a complete Arabic font?

Tags: fonts, internationalization, arabic

I have installed Arabic language support using the language tool, but I am still unable to get this page to render correctly:

http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/

Which fonts do I need to install to stop seeing squares instead of Arabic characters? I would prefer fonts that are available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: any solution? and btw I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/950484)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, **`fonts-hosny-amiri`** has the best Unicode coverage in my experience. Amiri is an Arabic Naskh style typographically oriented font.

**Description:**

> Amiri is a classical Arabic typeface in Naskh style for typesetting
> books and other running text.
>
> Its design is a revival of the beautiful typeface pioneered in early
> 20th century by Bulaq Press in Cairo, also known as Amiria Press, after
> which the font is named.
>
> Amiri font covers the full Unicode 6.0 Arabic and Arabic Supplement
> blocks, as well as the compatibility Arabic Presentation Forms-A and B
> blocks.

**Installation instructions:**

1. Enable universe repository

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository universe
   ```
2. Update package list

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the Amiri font

   ```
    sudo apt-get install fonts-hosny-amiri
   ```

It is available in most Debian derivatives:

- Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=amiri
- Debian: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=amiri

There are few other beautiful fonts listed in [Tanzil project](https://tanzil.net/docs/quranic_fonts). AFAIK, they don't cover completely the Arabic blocks in Unicode or have bad alignment with Latin script because some aim for Quran or pure Arabic text only not for mixed scripts.

Comment: I cannot find that font: `dpkg-query: no packages found matching ttf-hosny-amiri`

Comment: @BornToCode , `dpkg-query` seems to only packages that have been installed once at least. its name is `fonts-hosny-amiri` and it has a meta transitional package under `font-hosny-amiri` name. `apt-file find amiri` shows it as apt-file has its own contents database for all enabled repositories. See here where it is listed http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=amiri . I have updated installation instructions.

Comment: `sudo apt install fonts-hosny-amiri` works in debian too. I guess, `sudo apt update` is only needed.

Comment: @Ajeeb.K.P Yes, the package came from Debian (upstream). It is available in most RPM/DEB distributions, Anyway it is a font and can be installed directly without package.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install [ubuntu-restricted-extras [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras). It adds some more Microsoft fonts.

Comment: i think that doesnt provide those fonts https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: Yes, installing ubuntu-restriced-extras adds some Arabic fonts such as Arabic Transparent, which is very useful when sharing documents with windows users. Thanks Moussab

Answer (score 1):

The Language Support section in Ubuntu lets you change the interface language, in other words, the menus, panels and other elements. It has nothing to do with the way a web page is displayed.

I am no expert in Arabic, but usually, if a web page is not displayed correctly, what you need to change is its character encoding,
`View` -> `Character Encoding` in Firefox.

The source code of the page has the following:

```
charset=UTF-8

font-family: georgia, helvetica, times new roman, serif;
```

Comment: The Language Support tool in Ubuntu will install additional fonts depending on the language you select, I believe. Therefore, it *does* affect the way web pages are displayed. That particular page is encoded correctly, the issue is that I don't have a font installed that contains that particular Arabic character.

Comment: The problem for me was that the font-family got interpreted as "times new roman", which included (or refered to another font for) glyphs of some, but not all, arabic characters. Changing the font-family in css with firebug to have "scheherazade" as the first element renders all the arabic characters (correctly, I believe, but my arabic is very poor). This requires that one has `fonts-sil-scheherazade` package installed. Unfortunately, I don't know how to actually _fix_ the problem, instead of mucking around with manual css trickery.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu font now supports arabic. It will be the default for ubuntu 16.04.
You can download and try the font now from here:

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/227795932/ttf-ubuntu-font-family_0.84%7Emono0.83%2Barabicfontconfig-0ubuntu1_all.deb

Comment: Indeed in Ubuntu 16.04 it does not seem to support Arabic.

Comment: I am using 20.04 but it seems Ubuntu font fallbacks to DejaVu Sans for Arabic, unless I install Noto Sans Arabic UI.