Arabic text looks small on Facebook website
I've recently switched to Xubuntu 24.04 (Dual boot with Windows 11). But I noticed that the Arabic text (only on Facebook website so far) looks small and unreadable compared to English. It was readable on Windows and looked different. I tried both Firefox and Chrome, and the problem seems independent on the browser. The Arabic text looks normal on other websites like Google search and Youtube.

Try installing some Arabic fonts like https://askubuntu.com/a/439138, and then (if the problem still persists after restarting) go to browser settings, and set the hosny-amiri font as the default font for Arabic.
